# delay in audio sync after converting ac3 to aac

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac, x264, mp4box

I have a MKV video consist of a video and an audio of duration 10 minutes, after using ffmpeg to extract ac3 to aac audio, its duration became 10:50, which lead to audio out of sync with the video after packaging the new extracted audio to mp4 container using mp4box. how to solve the problem of syncing or as i knew, the delay that happen with aac encoding ? commands:

```
ffmpeg -i "d:/input.mkv" -vn -c:a aac "d:/audio.aac"

MP4Box 
-add "C:/1280x720.264" 
-fps "23.976023976024"
-add "d:/audio.aac:lang=ara"
```